# Docker Database is running, but I can't connect to it

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm attempting to create a database using docker, and docker says that it is running, but whenever I try to connect to it using

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d gleo -U postgres
```

it says database does not exist.

Here is my compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  postgres:

    image: postgres

    ports:

      - '5432:5432'

    environment:

      POSTGRES_DB: gleo

      POSTGRES_USER: postgres

      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

    volumes:

      - ./dataset:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

volumes:

  postgres-data:
```

Here are the logs:

```
Attaching to postgres-1
postgres-1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgres-1  | This user must also own the server process.
postgres-1  | 
postgres-1  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgres-1  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgres-1  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgres-1  | 
postgres-1  | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgres-1  | 
postgres-1  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
postgres-1  | creating subdirectories ... ok
postgres-1  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
postgres-1  | selecting default max_connections ... 100
postgres-1  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
postgres-1  | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
postgres-1  | creating configuration files ... ok
postgres-1  | running bootstrap script ... ok
postgres-1  | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
postgres-1  | syncing data to disk ... ok
postgres-1  | 
postgres-1  | 
postgres-1  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgres-1  | 
postgres-1  |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
postgres-1  | 
postgres-1  | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgres-1  | initdb: hint: You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
postgres-1  | waiting for server to start....2024-02-22 18:11:32.061 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bitpostgres-1  | 2024-02-22 18:11:32.066 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres-1  | 2024-02-22 18:11:32.073 UTC [51] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-02-22 18:11:31 UTC
postgres-1  | 2024-02-22 18:11:32.078 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres-1  |  done
postgres-1  | server started
postgres-1  | CREATE DATABASE
postgres-1  | 
postgres-1  | 
postgres-1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/GLEO_Schema.sql
postgres-1  | CREATE EXTENSION
postgres-1  | CREATE TABLE
postgres-1  | CREATE TABLE
postgres-1  | CREATE TABLE
postgres-1  | CREATE TABLE
postgres-1  | CREATE TABLE
postgres-1  | CREATE TABLE
postgres-1  | CREATE TABLE
postgres-1  | CREATE TABLE
postgres-1  | CREATE TABLE
postgres-1  | CREATE TABLE
postgres-1  | CREATE TABLE
postgres-1  | INSERT 0 1
postgres-1  | INSERT 0 1
postgres-1  | INSERT 0 1
postgres-1  | INSERT 0 1
postgres-1  | INSERT 0 1
postgres-1  | INSERT 0 1
postgres-1  | INSERT 0 1
postgres-1  | INSERT 0 1
postgres-1  | INSERT 0 1
postgres-1  | INSERT 0 1
postgres-1  | INSERT 0 1
postgres-1  | INSERT 0 1
postgres-1  | INSERT 0 1
postgres-1  | INSERT 0 1
postgres-1  | 
postgres-1  | 
postgres-1  | 2024-02-22 18:11:32.353 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgres-1  | waiting for server to shut down....2024-02-22 18:11:32.355 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgres-1  | 2024-02-22 18:11:32.357 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 54) exited with exit code 1
postgres-1  | 2024-02-22 18:11:32.357 UTC [49] LOG:  shutting down
postgres-1  | 2024-02-22 18:11:32.359 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
postgres-1  | 2024-02-22 18:11:32.443 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 972 buffers (5.9%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.012 s, sync=0.065 s, total=0.087 s; sync files=323, longest=0.021 s, average=0.001 s; distance=4436 kB, estimate=4436 kB; lsn=0/193FA90, redo lsn=0/193FA90
postgres-1  | 2024-02-22 18:11:32.447 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres-1  |  done
postgres-1  | server stopped
postgres-1  | 
postgres-1  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgres-1  | 
postgres-1  | 2024-02-22 18:11:32.473 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
postgres-1  | 2024-02-22 18:11:32.473 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres-1  | 2024-02-22 18:11:32.473 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres-1  | 2024-02-22 18:11:32.478 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres-1  | 2024-02-22 18:11:32.484 UTC [66] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-02-22 18:11:32 UTC
postgres-1  | 2024-02-22 18:11:32.489 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

And for reference, here is what I get when I attempt to directly connect to it:

```
PS C:\capstone-main\backend> psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d gleo -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "gleo" does not exist
```

I've looked around online and haven't found much regarding this. I have tried changing a few things though, like the name and the port, but they didn't seem to fix anything. I also tried deleting the image from docker desktop

EDIT:
Results of the docker run command

```
C:\capstone-main\backend>docker run --name my-postgres-container -e POSTGRES_DB=gleo -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -v ./dataset:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
Unable to find image 'postgres:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/postgres
e1caac4eb9d2: Pull complete
7a2930f13d47: Pull complete
a6c49e965138: Pull complete
ed8dc94f857d: Pull complete
1f07b4807698: Pull complete
a776288d4030: Pull complete
7cbb4adb3448: Pull complete
b6dbd7317d5f: Pull complete
52814b5dc710: Pull complete
b68697689b55: Pull complete
6d80681e3923: Pull complete
4270a9f40aee: Pull complete
d28fa0286314: Pull complete
cb1ee5bc271e: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:f58300ac8d393b2e3b09d36ea12d7d24ee9440440e421472a300e929ddb63460
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:latest
bc33899405b0e73754c4af51ad56c101e4c83f7097d8400b7f6b32e2dcb57e34
```

Attempting to connect both while the db is running or not gives the following:

```
C:\capstone-main\backend>psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d gleo
Password for user postgres:
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "gleo" does not exist
```

Comment: how did you start the docker image?  Did you publish port 5432?  Show us the `docker run` command.

Comment: When I try to replicate your issue (without any initialization scripts), it creates the database just fine. Just to verify that you're actually connecting to the container, can you try running the `psql` command when the container is down, please?

Comment: @erik258 I use docker compose up to start the docker image. To my knowledge, listing the ports in the compose file should publish them, although when I try to manually create it from a command and specifically publish them it doesn't work either.

Comment: @HansKilian The psql command gives the same result whether the container is running or not

Comment: "localhost" (::1)" have you tried 127.0.0.1 ?  Might be worth testing

Answer (score 0):

The docker container automatically creates its own network that's separate from our local network. so we need to specify the network and restart the docker container. After that, you can connect to the database. try this.

```
  version: '3.9'

  services:
    postgres:
      image: postgres
      ports:
        - '5432:5432'
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: gleo
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      volumes:
        - ./dataset:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      networks:
        - my-network

  networks:
    my-network:
      driver: bridge
```

Comment: I gave it a shot, but all it gives me is:
services.networks Additional property my-network is not allowed